# how it is vs how is it / how that is vs how is that

Tags: meaning, grammar, questions

I'm very confused about how to use these. They sound pretty much the same to me:

> - How is it possible?
> - How it is possible (should I put a question mark here?)

> - How is that possible?
> - How that is possible

Is it correct if I say: We did it again! How it's possible?

Could you please tell me when should I use which one?

Comment: The first version listed ("How is it possible?") is the standard way of asking in the United States, Canada, England, Australia, etc.

The second version ("How it is possible?") is how English speakers in India ask this.

Answer (score 7):

If you are asking a question, you should invert the subject and the auxiliary:

> How is it possible?
>
> How is that possible?

If the question is embedded in another sentence, don't invert them:

> Do you know **how it is possible**?
>
> He asked me **how it was possible**.

For yes/no questions, we don't always invert them in informal speech:

> Are you going? (formal or informal)
>
> You're going? (informal)

but when there is a question word (who, what, why, where, how etc.) that is not the subject, we always invert even in informal speech.

**Edited**: to add the proviso "that is not the subject" in the last sentence.